# Aligned LaTeX equations SymPy

Tags: python, latex, sympy

SymPy will pretty print expressions within a `dict` like this:

```
>>> latex(dict(a=1, b=2))
'\\left \\{ a : 1, \\quad b : 2\\right \\}'
```

Instead I'd like to use the `align` environment to split my expressions across lines, with an output like this:

```
\begin{align}
a & = 1 \\
b & = 2 \\
\end{align}
```

Can SymPy do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in option for this, but you can subclass LatexPrinter and override its method [`_print_dict`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/latex.py#L1610) to do whatever you want, like this:

```
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter

class MyPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_dict(self, d):
        keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=default_sort_key)
        items = []

        for key in keys:
            val = d[key]
            items.append("%s & = %s" % (self._print(key), self._print(val)))

        return r"\begin{align} %s \end{align}" % r", \\ ".join(items)
```

Example of use:

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(MyPrinter().doprint(mydict))   #  \begin{align} a & = 1, \\ b & = 2 \end{align}
```

The `latex` function is just a shortcut for `LatexPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)`, you can redefine it accordingly:

```
latex = lambda expr, **settings: MyPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)
```

so that `latex` has the new behavior.

Speaking of settings, one can also introduce a setting for this, so that both printing methods are available; but at that stage it's probably better to add an issue and PR to [SymPy repo](https://github.com/sympy/sympy).

Comment: You should use `aligned` not `align`, else printing of `dict(a=1, b=dict(c=2))` will  fail